# Зависимость скорости передачи данных от длины сообщения

Tags: архитектура

Почему реальная скорость передачи данных по сети зависит от длины передаваемых сообщений и отличается от заявленной фирмой-производителем величины? При каких условиях этого отличия не существовало бы?

Comment: А какие собственные мысли есть по этому вопросу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Длина передаваемого сообщения ограничена и сверху и снизу.

- Если передавать очень большие сообщения, то при искажении хотя бы одного бита необходимо передавать всё сообщение заново.
- Если передавать очень маленькие сообщения, то служебная информация начинает занимать большой процент самого сообщения. К примеру, в технологии ATM размер пакета составляет 53 байта, из них 5 байт служебная информация, т.е. почти 10%.

Так же, канал к которому Вы подключены (скорее всего), подключено ещё некоторое количество абонентов и все они хотят использовать канал, но т.к. в один момент времени по кабелю может передавать данные только один компьютер, то у всех остальных возникает простой. Всё это усугубляется тем, что моменты времени передачи данных неизвестны, т.е. все работают асинхронно. Может произойти такое, что один начал передавать данные и второй, таким образом происходит коллизия (два сообщения смешиваются) и сообщения надо будет передавать заново.